# How do I add a custom jQuery plug in to MS Outlook 2010?

Tags: jquery, outlook-addin, outlook-2010, shapeshift

I tried going through the official documents such as

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/addin-tutorial#update-the-manifest-1

But they are dealing with the xml file there.
I wish to add jQuery Shapeshift to my Outlook but there is no such xml file added there. The source is

https://github.com/AshesOfOwls/jquery.shapeshift

So how can I add Shapeshift to my outlook? I intend to add it to the backstage view if possible

Comment: Any advice will be appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Office Add-ins are not supported for Office 2010 edition. This, obviously, includes Outlook as well. There are certain [client requirement to run Office.js](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/concepts/requirements-for-running-office-add-ins#client-requirements-windows-desktop-and-tablet) add-ins. Office 2013 or later required to run add-in on Windows platform. You may run add-ins on Office Online web clients, including Outlook online.